# Button in Custom Dialog Android

Tags: android, button, customdialog

This is my code

```
    protected void markerTouched(Marker marker) {


                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);


                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);


                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

                dialog.show();      

                 Button declineButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.b_close);
                    // if decline button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                    declineButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // Close dialog
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
     }
```

i have found an error in this line:

```
 declineButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
```

the error on `setOnClickListner`:

> The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){})

and other in `OnClickListener`():

> The type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method DialogInterface.OnClickListener.onClick(DialogInterface, int)

someone can explain what i've to do?

Comment: Wrong import. use `import android.view.View.OnClickListener`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");


Button dialog_btn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button);
dialog_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    // Perform button logic
}
```

this is important:

```
dialog_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

**View.OnClcikListener**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you have the wrong import. Since you are setting `onClickListener` for a Button you need  `View.OnClickListener` but the import is `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
declineButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }




});
```